# How to convert a List of lists with nested dictionaries and lists within each list to a pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas

### I am trying to convert the following output to a pandas Dataframe

```html
[{'category': "Best restaurant that's been around forever and is still worth the trip", 'winner': ['Lula Cafe'], 'runners_up': ['Frontera Grill', 'Chicago Diner ', 'Sabatino’s', 'Twin Anchors']}] [{'category': 'Best fancy restaurant in Chicago', 'winner':
['Alinea '], 'runners_up': ['Blackbird', 'Girl & the Goat', 'Green Zebra', 'The Publican']}] [{'category': 'Best bang for your buck', 'winner': ['Big Star', 'Sultan’s Market'], 'runners_up': ['Frasca Pizzeria & Wine Bar', 'Chutney Joe’s', '"My boyfriend!"']}]
[{'category': 'Best chef', 'winner': ['Rick Bayless (Frontera Grill, Topolobampo, Xoco)'], 'runners_up': ['Grant Achatz (Alinea, Next, The Aviary)', 'Stephanie Izard (Girl & the Goat)']}]
```

```
I am expecting a dataframe with column names as category, winner and runner's up respectively and entries into subsequent columns.Any suggestions




here is the code:
Im basically trying to scrape a web page with beautiful Soup.(though jus a  beginner)

    def make_soup(url):
        page = requests.get(url)
        return BeautifulSoup(page.content,'lxml')

    # function to get all the categories corresponding to a url
    def get_category(section_url):
        soup = make_soup(section_url)
        boccat = soup.find('dl','boccat')
        category_links = [base_url + dd.a['href'] for dd in boccat.find_all('dd')]
        return category_links

    #function to print winner and runner's up pertaining to each category
    def category_winner(category_url):
        soup = make_soup(category_url)
        category = soup.find('h1','headline').string
        winner = [h2.string for h2 in soup.findAll("h2", "boc1")]
        runners_up = [h2.string for h2 in soup.findAll("h2", "boc2")]
        return {'category' : category,
            'winner' : winner,
            'runners_up' : runners_up}


    # url for which the winners are to be found
    food_n_drink = ('https://www.chicagoreader.com/chicago/best-of-chicago-2011-
    food-drink/BestOf?oid=4106228')

    categories = get_category(food_n_drink)
    data = []
    for cat in categories:
        winner = category_winner(cat)
        data.append(winner)
        print(data)
```

The last line of code gives the output i.e multiple lists, the first 4 of which i had shared in my question.My aim to create a dataframe from the output to put it to use

Comment: Is this a list of lists? Or each in a single seperate list?

[{'category': "Best restaurant that's been around forever and is still worth the trip", 'winner': ['Lula Cafe'], 'runners_up': ['Frontera Grill', 'Chicago Diner ', 'Sabatino’s', 'Twin Anchors']}] can be considered as 1 list, and the next can be considered as the second list?

Comment: Each list is separate in itself.It isn't a list of lists.Each list contains a category and a winner and runner's up for each category respectively. This is the exact output i got after i executed a chunk of code.

Comment: This means, every print statement inside a for loop printed each list one after another. Could I see a bit of code that printed the list? If you add the code that printed the list, I can give you an answer immediately.

Answer (score 0):

If `k` is a list of lists seperated by comma:

`[{'category': "Best restaurant that's been around forever and is still worth the trip", 'winner': ['Lula Cafe'], 'runners_up': ['Frontera Grill', 'Chicago Diner ', 'Sabatino’s', 'Twin Anchors']}] , [{'category': 'Best fancy restaurant in Chicago', 'winner':['Alinea '], 'runners_up': ['Blackbird', 'Girl & the Goat', 'Green Zebra', 'The Publican']}] , [{'category': 'Best bang for your buck', 'winner': ['Big Star', 'Sultan’s Market'], 'runners_up': ['Frasca Pizzeria & Wine Bar', 'Chutney Joe’s', '"My boyfriend!"']}] , [{'category': 'Best chef', 'winner': ['Rick Bayless (Frontera Grill, Topolobampo, Xoco)'], 'runners_up': ['Grant Achatz (Alinea, Next, The Aviary)', 'Stephanie Izard (Girl & the Goat)']}]`

then

```
emptydict = {}
diction = {}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(emptydict, orient='index')
df = df.T

for i in k:
    for j in i:
        for key, value in j.items():

            diction[key] = value

        df = df.append(diction, ignore_index=True, verify_integrity=False)
```

will do the job.

Answer (score -1):

You can make a pandas dataframe from a list of dictionaries or a list of lists. Your output is separate dictionaries wrapped into separate lists. If you define them as dictionaries or lists, or a list of dicts or lists, you can create a df from them.

Reformatted input:

```
d1 = {'category': "Best restaurant that's been around forever and is still worth the trip",
  'winner': ['Lula Cafe'], 
  'runners_up': ['Frontera Grill', 'Chicago Diner ', 'Sabatino’s', 'Twin Anchors']}

d2 = {'category': 'Best fancy restaurant in Chicago', 
  'winner': ['Alinea '],
  'runners_up': ['Blackbird', 'Girl & the Goat', 'Green Zebra', 'The Publican']}

d3 = {'category': 'Best bang for your buck', 
  'winner': ['Big Star', 'Sultan’s Market'], 
  'runners_up': ['Frasca Pizzeria & Wine Bar', 'Chutney Joe’s', '"My boyfriend!"']}

d4 = {'category': 'Best chef', 
  'winner': ['Rick Bayless (Frontera Grill, Topolobampo, Xoco)'],
  'runners_up': ['Grant Achatz (Alinea, Next, The Aviary)', 'Stephanie Izard (Girl & the Goat)']}
```

Create the df:

```
pd.DataFrame([d1, d2, d3, d4])
```

Comment: It can be done one a list of dictionaries or a list of lists.

Comment: Yeah, my bad. Edited to reflect. OP is lists separated by spaces; needs to be a list of lists or a list of dicts.

Comment: Lists seperated by spaces? You mean lists seperated by commas.. If it is a list of lists, then each list inside will be seperated by a comma right?

Comment: The original post is four lists separated by spaces.